# PHP Mysqli Select Multiple rows data foreach provided

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to fetch three things from 2 different tables for each `ID` i.e for me `RegID`

1. My first query is to select `DISTINCT RegID from table_one` if there are more than one it should select all in where `AttendanceStatus =Absent` and `AttendanceDate = Todays_date`
2. for each `RegID` selected it should select `DISTINCT Subjects` and `Standard` from same `table_one`
3. the same id it should select mobile number from `table_two` and it should echo then repeat for second  `RegID` if exist the same should be repeated until last `RegID`

i am getting the `DISTINCT`  regid but in the same while statement if am using the fetch result to get subject and  standard along with register id it give me only one id , subject and  standard and am not getting how to solve this

**My EDIT**
Now in my example database  i have two entries that says absent in `AttendanceStatus` so in my first select i vl remove duplicate if exist  and select those **2`RegID` that is working fine** now for that each `RegID` i want to select    `Standard` and  `subject` in my second query that is in while statement tough there are two `RegID` it is giving me only one  i need those two absent reg to be shown up along with there respective distinct subject and standards

**To be simple**

1. First `RegID` select who ever are absent by removing duplicate
2. Select `Standard` and `Subjects` for the first selected    `RegID's`
3. Echo separately `RegID` , `Standard` and `Subjects` for each  `RegID`

My table_one data base

```
AttendanceDate           Standard           Subjects        RegID   AttendanceStatus        
2016-01-08 00:00:00     III BSc PCM     PHY/CHEM PRACTICAL  1382043         Present
2016-01-08 00:00:00     III BSc PCM     PHY/CHEM PRACTICAL  1382044         Present
2016-01-08 00:00:00     III BSc PCM     PHY/CHEM PRACTICAL  1382045         Present
2016-01-08 00:00:00     III BSc PCM     PHY/CHEM PRACTICAL  1382046         Absent
2016-01-08 00:00:00     III BSc PCM     PHY/CHEM PRACTICAL  1382047         Absent
```

PHP Mysqli code

```
$query="SELECT DISTINCT RegID FROM table_one WHERE AttendanceDate='2016-01-08 00:00:00' and AttendanceStatus='Absent'" ;
$data=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
if(mysqli_num_rows($data) > 0) {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
        $StudentRegID= $row['RegID'];
        $query="SELECT   DISTINCT(CONCAT(Standard,Subjects)) AS standard_and_subject , RegID FROM table_one WHERE AttendanceDate='2016-01-08 00:00:00' and RegID='$StudentRegID'" ;
        $data=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
        if(mysqli_num_rows($data) > 0) {
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
                if($row['RegID'] != '' && $row['RegID'] != NULL){
                    $RegID = $row['RegID'];
                    $standard_and_subject = $row['standard_and_subject'];
                    echo $standard_and_subject;
                    echo $RegID;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need multiple rows inplace of one row right ? or you need all regid in one array and standard and subject in one array like this ? how you will get it can you explain it ?

Comment: @jilesh yes but for specific id and in final i need to select one value from different table too as i have mentioned in point no 3

Comment: please can you edit your post and set what you get currently and what you expect ?

Comment: @jilesh  i have edited my post please let me know any thing u need \

Answer (score 2):

Use a single query with a `JOIN`, rather than queries inside the `foreach` loop. And instead of checking for an empty `RegID` in PHP, filter them out in the SQL.

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT t1.RegID, CONCAT(t2.Standard, t2.Subjects) AS standard_and_subject
          FROM (SELECT DISTINCT RegID
                FROM table_one
                WHERE AttendanceDate='2016-01-08 00:00:00'
                AND AttendanceStatus='Absent'
                AND RegID != ''
                AND RegID IS NOT NULL) AS t1
          JOIN table_one AS t2 ON t1.RegID = t2.RegID
          WHERE t2.AttendanceData = '2016-01-08 00:00:00'";
$data = mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error());
if (mysqli_num_rows($data) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {
        echo $row['standard_and_subject'];
        echo $row['RegID'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your store the mysql object result in same variable name

Try this coding

```
 while($standard_row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){

                    if($standard_row['RegID'] != '' && $standard_row['RegID'] != NULL){
                        $RegID = $standard_row['RegID'];

                            $standard_and_subject = $standard_row['standard_and_subject'];
                        echo $standard_and_subject;
                        echo $RegID;

                    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply the same i did in the second query but though there are two reg id it gives me only result for the first one

Comment: if you need first one use echo  $StudentRegID; and second one use echo $standard_row['RegID'];